# Microsoft Graph API - Uploaded file can not be opened

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

I am trying to upload a file using the Microsoft Graph API. It seems to upload OK, but when trying to open the file I am told that it can not be opened.

Here's the relavent part of my PHP code. I've using Guzzle to make the requests.

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['foo']['tmp_name']);

$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$sent_options = [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/plain'
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        base64_encode($data)
    ]
];

$guzzle->put($url, $sent_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've worked it out... for anyone else with the same problem, here's the solution.

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['foo']['tmp_name']);

$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$sent_options = [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/plain'
    ],
    'body' => $data
];

$guzzle->put($url, $sent_options);
```